# pandas new column counting id's existence in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, multiple-columns

This is my initial dataframe dfA :

| idA | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row |
| 2 | data |
| 3 | data |

dataframe dfB

| idC | idA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |

I am trying to count every id existence of dfA in dfB , and add to new column like this:

| idA | data | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row | 2 |
| 2 | data | 0 |
| 3 | data | 4 |

how can i do this plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` then `count` to get the count of `idC` in each group `idA`. At last, `map` the count Series to `idA` column of `df1`.

```py
df1['count'] = df1['idA'].map(df2.groupby('idA')['idC'].count()).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

```
print(df1)

   idA  data  count
0    1   row    2
1    2  data    0
2    3  data    4
```